# deploying IronPython script or static building an application

Tags: .net, python, windows, ironpython, ironpython-studio

I created an IronPython script that imports from Python libraries, such as `os`, `sys`, etc. as well as .NET libraries.

It runs perfectly fine from my Visual Studio IronPython solution but I need to deploy this so other people who don't have IronPython or Python installed can run it.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 12):

Requirements:

- `ipy.exe` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7.1\`
- `pyc.py` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7.1\Tools\Scripts\`
- `MyProgram.py` would be your program.

  1. Inside your project folder (where `MyProgram.py` is), create a folder called "deploy."
  2. Run `cd deploy` in the command prompt.
  3. Run `"C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7.1\ipy.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7.1\Tools\Scripts\pyc.py" /main:..\MyProgram.py /target:exe`

This will generate a dll and an exe for MyProgram in the `deploy` folder.

If you try to run `MyProgram.exe` and you're importing libraries like `os`, you may get a `No module named ...`.

Since, I'm using `os`, I get this error:

If you run "MyProgram.exe" and you're using standard libraries, you might get `No module named...` errors.

In my case, I got:

> Unhandled Exception: IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException: No module na med os 
>   ...

To fix this issue, copy `Lib` folder from `C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7.1\` to the `deploy` folder you just created. Then, before you import the libraries which are throwing errors, modify `MyProgram.py` like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("Lib")

# Followed by library imports that were causing you trouble:
import os
```

As a last step, copy the following files from `C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7.1\` to `deploy` folder as well:

-`IronPython.dll`
-`IronPython.Modules.dll`
-`Microsoft.Dynamic.dll`
-`Microsoft.Scripting.dll`

Now you can zip up your `deploy` folder and and ship it!